# Can you see me?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

The answer to this riddle, if you look around,
Is hidden in plain sight, right above the ground.
It can be found in the ocean, but not in sky.
In apples and oranges, but never in pie.

In lakes and in water, but not in most rivers.
Not found in movement, not even in shivers.
Now find the answer, within all of these lines,
but not in this riddle, or one of its signs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it something like

> The letter A

Most explanations would be obvious except for the stretch that

> "[R]ight above the ground" refers to the word "around" which is physically above the phrase "the ground" in the original riddle.

As a more complete solution:

> The answer to this riddle, if you look [**A**round],
>    Is hidden in [pl**A**in sight], right *above* [the ground].
>    It can be found in [the oce**A**n], but not in [sky].
>    In [**A**pples] and [or**A**nges], but never in [pie].
>
>    In [l**A**kes] and in [w**A**ter], but not in [most rivers].
>    Not found in [movement], not even in [shivers].
>    Now find the answer, within [**A**ll of these lines],
>    but not in [this riddle], or [one of its signs].

Comment: @Devsman but not in `guvf evqqyr`

Comment: @question_asker That's the point right? It's not in `bar bs vgf fvtaf`, either.

Comment: that's how I read it, anyway (this was going to be my guess for the same reasons you've stated here)

Comment: Well done. Also, in the actual format of the riddle, **a**round is right above *the ground*.

Comment: @AggieKidd Ooh, I like the use of spatial relationships.

Comment: It took you less than 7 minutes to find the answer.. wow how did you do that? I tried to find the answer and honestly the letter _A_ never cross to my mind.

Comment: @Isa There are many riddles that talk about finding something in one place but not another and the answer is a letter. For instance, "What happens twice in a week, once in a year, but never in a month?" The letter E. I looked for and found a letter that fit the bill this time.

Comment: This is really nice. It makes you think and at the same time it's funny :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> the letter *a*

The answer to this riddle, if you look around,

> both *answer* and *around* start with *a*

Is hidden in plain sight, right above the ground.

> in the middle of *plain* and at start of *above*

It can be found in the ocean, but not in sky.

> *a* in *ocean* not in *sky*

In apples and oranges, but never in pie.

> in *apples and oranges* not *pie*

In lakes and in water, but not in most rivers.

> in *lakes and in water* not *most rivers*

Not found in movement, not even in shivers.

> not in any words here.

Now find the answer, within all of these lines,

> in *answer* and *all*

but not in this riddle, or one of its signs.

> not in any words here.

Comment: Well done, just a little behind Engineer.

Comment: Thanks, was about half way through when I saw someone else posted :/